# Yii2 installing extensions

Tags: php, macos, yii2

**Hi,
I have just installed a Yii2 basic project from composer. I'm in mac osx yosemite 10.10.
Neverthless i'm trying to install extensions as descrived in the tutorials from Yii guide 2.0 and i cannot do it, simply to the fact that i don´t know where to put the line:**

**php composer.phar require --prefer-dist arturoliveira/yii2-tileslidemenu "*"**

this method says in terminal it cannot find composer.phar.
Where to put the above line ?

When i installed the project "acastro" i wrote in terminal the line:
composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic acastro

and the installation worked very well (i had to deal with the mcrypt missing error first but then composer was recognized as a command by termnal)

So, what is the issue here, since nothing installs in vendors dir?

---

I have tried the other method but nothng happens. The method was:

**"arturoliveira/yii2-tileslidemenu": "*"**

added in the required section of composr.json file.

When i launch the project by localhost MAMP, nothing is installed in vendors dir.

---

Anyone can explain me how to install the proper way an extension in Yii2. In Yii1.1 was so easy to do it.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you have global installation of composer and you do `composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic acastro`, than you can do same with that line too:

```
composer require --prefer-dist arturoliveira/yii2-tileslidemenu "*"
```

I don't use MAMP, only XAMPP, but as far as I know, you have to manually do composer actions via command line.

Comment: Navigated to the project folder and in terminal executed without php word, the command composer, and now i have successfully installed an Yii2 extension.